# SyntaxError: invalid label using jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to make an Ajax call to my server using the following *jQuery* call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "http://iceworld.sls-atl.com/api/&cmd=time",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(error);
    },
});
```

I get the data that I expect from the browser, but Firebug keeps saying "SyntaxError: invalid label" as shown below:

[image: invalid label]

So, what puzzles me is the reason why the error callback is called instead of success. I'm wondering what I did wrong here.

Comment: Looks like valid JSON to me, still I get `Unexpected token :` in Chrome.

Comment: Looking at the response from that URL it comes in as `text/HTML` not `test/JSON`. Although you'd hope that jQuery could cope with that.

Answer (score 7):

JSONP data must be returned in the format: `callback( jsonObject )`.  That is why you are getting an `invalid label` error.  It is expecting a function, not a JSON object.  You need to modify your server code to wrap the return value with the name of the callback function.  The name is automatically added to the request by jQuery when you request JSONP.  If you watch the request, you should see something like this:

```
http://iceworld.sls-atl.com/api/&cmd=time?callback=jQuery191035087670385837555_1365126604422&_=1365126604423
```

Your script needs to take the `callback` parameter and use that to wrap the data, so for this example it would look like this:

```
jQuery191035087670385837555_1365126604422({"status":1,"data":"1365126534"})
```

If you are accessing the server from the same origin, you could simply use JSON instead.

Comment: How would you go about warping the data with the callback?

Comment: On the server end?  Literally, you take your JSON string, and put the callback function name around it.  So, instead of returning `{"data":"mydata"}`, return `callbackName({"data":"mydata"})`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to clearly answer without more details and without the response sent by the server. But looking at this, it looks like the server is returning valid JSON; not a JSONP wrapper function. Try to change the `dataType` to `JSON` (*no promise though, would need more info to be sure*)

Answer (score 0):

Your json return value should be in the format **function_name(json_data)**.

 like this:

```
return({"status":a,"data":"123456789"})
```

create a function as '**return**' or same name give with json return value. and the **return** function will be called automatically  when there is a response.

```
 $.ajax(
{
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: "http://iceworld.sls-atl.com/api/&cmd=time",

  error: function(error)
  {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(error);
  },
} );

function return()
{

console.log(data);

}
```

hop it will work fine